# Takeoff plane in SITL: calibration fails

Tags: dronekit

I am testing SITL with DroneKit, and I cannot seem to make a plane take off. When I do `arm throttle`, the console says:

> APM: PreArm: 3D accel cal needed

I tried to run `accelcal`, and it asks me to calibrate the plane like so:

```
APM: Place vehicle level and press any key.
APM: Place vehicle on its LEFT side and press any key.
APM: Place vehicle on its RIGHT side and press any key.
APM: Place vehicle nose DOWN and press any key.
APM: Place vehicle nose UP and press any key.
APM: Place vehicle on its BACK and press any key.
APM: AccelRange: 0.0 0.0 0.0
APM: Insufficient accel range
APM: AccelRange: 0.0 0.0 0.0
APM: Insufficient accel range
APM: Calibration FAILED
```

How can I calibrate my plane in SITL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/plane-sitlmavproxy-tutorial/). I actually had to load parameters for the plane first:

```
param load ../Tools/autotest/ArduPlane.parm
```

I had to do it once, and now they are loaded automatically.